# Concatenated string is not recognized by my Sub

Tags: vba, excel

I made the following `Sub` to help me copy values from other workbooks or even just from other sheets within the same workbook.

```
Private Sub CopyValues(fromSheet As String, fromRange As String, toSheet As String, toRange As String, Optional fromFileName As String = "")

    Dim toFile As Excel.Workbook
    Set toFile = ActiveWorkbook

    Dim fromFile As Excel.Workbook
        If Len(fromFileName) > 0 Then
            Set fromFile = Workbooks.Open(fromFileName)
        Else
            Set fromFile = ActiveWorkbook
        End If

    With ActiveWorkbook
        toFile.Sheets(toSheet).Range(toRange).Value = fromFile.Sheets(fromSheet).Range(fromRange).Value
    End With

    If Len(fromFileName) > 0 Then
        fromFile.Close savechanges:=False
    End If

End Sub
```

It works pretty well (and you all are free to use it if you find it helpful). Below is an example of code that works:

```
Call CopyValues(reportName, "B4:C15", reportName, "E2:F13", reportDirPath)
```

Unfortunately, I'm having trouble with a specific case. I'm looking to copy the same value into multiple cells in the same column. Below is what I came up with:

```
For i = 2 To i = 13
    Call CopyValues(reportName, "AJ2", reportName, "H" + i, reportDirPath)
    Next i
```

That didn't work. No error messages, but none of the values were pasted into my sheet. I thought that maybe concatenating the integer `i` was converting (is that the technical word?) the string to a different type, so I tried the following:

```
For i = 2 To i = 13
    Call CopyValues(reportName, "AJ2", reportName, CStr("H" + i), reportDirPath)
    Next i
```

That still didn't work. Same deal. No error messages, but none of the values were pasted into my sheet.

Changing the `+` to an `&` also didn't work:

```
For i = 2 To i = 13
    Call CopyValues(reportName, "AJ2", reportName, CStr("H" & i), reportDirPath)
    Next i
```

Obviously, I could just write out each individual case, but that seems kind of ridiculous. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Why don't you `Call CopyValues(reportName, "AJ2", reportName, "H2:H13", reportDirPath)` instead?

Comment: Wow. I had no idea that could work. Just did it and it worked like a charm. You're a genius @Sgdva! Just for curiosity's sake, though, anyone have any idea why my original code didn't work?

Comment: The `With ActiveWorkbook` in your function has no impact - you could delete it

Comment: Thanks @TimWilliams! I hate unnecessary code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I tried your code your 'For' loops were not working, but after I changed your for loop to say 'For i = 2 to 13' as opposed to 'For i=2 To i = 13' the last version of your code worked for me.

```
For i = 2 To 13
    Call CopyValues("Sheet1", "A1", "Sheet2", CStr("J" & i))
    Next i
End Sub
```

So I think that could have been your trouble.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into this.